# Reading parenthesis from fstream object. C++

Tags: c++, ifstream

I opened a .txt file with an ifstream object named `input`. If a new line starts with a "(" then it doesn't read it how I want it to.  The expected output doesn't get printed, then it exits the loops. I want it to only jump out of the while loop when it reaches the end of the file.  What am I doing wrong?  My do while loop and my .txt file are below.

```
char c;
int i;
do
{
    if(input.peek( ) == '(' || input.peek( ) == ')')
    {
        input >> c;
        cout << c;
    }else if(input.peek( ) == '+' || input.peek( ) == '-' || input.peek( ) == '*' || input.peek( ) == '/')
    {
        input >> c;
        cout << c;
    }else
    {
        input >> i;
        cout << i;
    }

}while(input && input.peek( ) != EOF);
```

Here is the .txt file, each on a separate line:

```
(3)
(3)
4
(5+7)-(5*3)
```

This is my output:

```
 (3)3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I'm pretty certain that the problem is that `input.peek()` is returning a newline after `')'` has been read. Then `input >> i;` doesn't read a number, and `i` remains the value it had before, so the output is `3`. You could quickly try this by adding `i = 42;` before `input >> i;` - if the output becomes `(3)42`, then I'm right.

If I'm right, you will want to add a bit of code to handle `isspace()` or something similar.

May I also suggest that you do something like `cpeek = input.peek();`, before the first `if`, and then use `if (cpeek == '(' || cpeek == ')')...` etc.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly it.  Any suggestions on how to handle the the line return?  This is what I have right now, but it still isn't working how I'd like: if(input.peek() == '\n') {cout << endl; input >> c;}  The first char of every line is missing.

Comment: `cin.ignore();` perhaps? Or `cin.get();` would work in this case.

Comment: Perfect.  You are the best.  I used `input.ignore()`.